# Using parenthesized Regex backreferences in StringReplace

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

(I am sorry for my poor English,I'll try to use a simple sentence to convey me.)

I can use `StringCases` to get the target to change like this

```
StringCases["aaabccccc",RegularExpression["(\\w)(\\1+)"] -> "$2"]
```

> {"aa", "cccc"}

But now,I want to use `StringReplace` to transform the target.How can I use the `StringReplace` to transform the parenthesized regular expression?Help me please.

Ps:My aim is `"axxbcxxxx"`

---

Somebody will assert the regular expression cannot do this,but I can cope the question in Python with regular expression.Like this:

```
    >>> re.sub(r'(\w)(\1+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + 'x' * len(m.group(2)),'aaabccccc')

    'axxbcxxxx'
```

But I want to get the solution in *Mathematica*. (T_T).

Comment: Just use `StringReplace["aaabccccc", 
 y : Repeated[x_] :> 
  x <> StringJoin[ConstantArray["x", StringLength@y - 1]]]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this using *Mathematica's* native string patterns is like this:

```
StringReplace["aaabccccc",
  xs:((x:WordCharacter)..) :> StringPadRight[x, StringLength@xs, "x"] ]

(* "axxbcxxxx" *)
```

Here is the same replacement expressed using a `RegularExpression`:

```
StringReplace["aaabccccc",
  RegularExpression["((\\w)\\2+)"] :> StringPadRight["$2", StringLength@"$1", "x"] ]

(* "axxbcxxxx" *)
```

It is possible to perform this transformation using a simple regular expression without callbacks -- but only if we reverse the string first (and unreverse the result afterwards):

```
StringReplace[StringReverse @ "aaabccccc",
  RegularExpression["(\\w)(?=\\1)"] -> "x" ] // StringReverse

(* "axxbcxxxx" *)
```

The reversal is necessary due to restrictions in the use of look-behind regular expressions:

```
(* caution: should theoretically work, but doesn't in practice *)
StringReplace["aaabccccc", RegularExpression["(\\w)(?<=\\1\\1)"] -> "x"]

(* RegularExpression::msg25: Lookbehind assertion is not fixed length... *)
```

The PCRE regular expression engine used by *Mathematica* neither allows variable-length look-behind assertions nor detects that the look-behind in this case is actually of fixed length.  By reversing the string we are able to convert the look-behind assertion into a look-ahead, which is not subject to these limitations.

---

**StringPadRight**

`StringPadRight` was introduced in version 10.1 of *Mathematica*.  In earlier versions, we can define our own:

```
stringPadRight[s_String, n_Integer, p_String] :=
  PadRight[ToCharacterCode@s, n, ToCharacterCode@p] // FromCharacterCode
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Regexes:

```
StringReplace["aaabccccc", RegularExpression["(\\w)(\\1+)"] :> 
                                     StringJoin["$1", Array["x" &, StringLength@"$2"]]]
(* "axxbcxxxx" *)
```